# Joining Existing WRT120N Wireless Network with Belkin N450

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have an existing wireless network provided by a Linksys WRT120N router.

We have a media device that *requires ethernet*, and was previously plugged into one of the LAN ports on the router.

**We're moving the media device** to another portion of the house, and we don't want to run a 50ft ethernet cable. Thus, we picked up a Belkin N450 router to connect to the *existing* wireless network, and provide network access via its 4 LAN ports.

But, I can't figure out how to use the Belkin router as a wireless access point. It has an Access Point page, but it seems to be for connecting to a wired network. (Providing a static IP, etc.)

**How can we configure our Belkin N450 to connect to an existing wireless network, and provide network connectivity to its 4 LAN ports?**

I would also be fine with swapping roles, so the Belkin N450 acts as the main router, and the Linksys WRT120N joins the existing wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into these routers before, and the n450 doesn't serve well as an accesspoint. I would recommend swapping roles to use the Linksys as the AP... but there's some setup to get this working, found this answer from another website specific to your model, post it here for ease of read, future droplink...

> You should assign the WRT120N a static IP address that is outside of
>   DHCP scope of your existing router. An easy way figuring one out is to
>   take the IP address of your router and add one. Assign this new number
>   to the LAN address of the router (Note that you will be connecting
>   this wireless router to your existing network via one of the 4 LAN
>   ports, the WAN port is left unused)
>
> Next shut off the DHCP server in the WRT120N, your existing router
>   will be dishing out IP leases, so the one in the WRT120N is not needed
>   (and if left on will cause issues). While you are in the GUI, set up
>   the wireless settings as you wish.
>
> Once these setups are completed you can safely connect this router to
>   your network and have it work as an access point. If you need to
>   change a setting in the GUI (ie change your wireless key) you just
>   need to remember the static IP address you assigned it.
>   [Source](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r24293660-WRT120N-As-an-Access-Point)

Comment: I found that answer, but unfortunately it's for a user with a WRT120N who wants to connect to an existing *wired* network, and provide wireless. I need to connect to an existing *wireless* network, and provide the ethernet connectivity. (But I reached the same conclusion you did about the N450, it looks like it will be going back to the store.)

Comment: A friend of mine uses a homeplug(https://www.homeplug.org/home/) and he says it works great... maybe this could feed your router?